# Limit the result from FetchXML query in CRM online 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-online, fetchxml

I am using a service that gets data from CRM ONLINE and transfers it to SQL database for reporting purposes. I am using the following Fetch XML query to query CRM

```
 string fetchXml = string.Format(@"<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
                              <entity name='new_studentinformation' enableprefiltering ='1'                                                                    prefilterparametername='CRM_Filterednew_studentinformation'>
                                    <attribute name='new_studentid' />
                                    <attribute name='new_primaryhomeroom' />
                                    <attribute name='new_lastname' />
                                    <attribute name='new_firstname' />
                                    <attribute name='new_busnumber' />
                                    <attribute name='new_schoolname' />  
                                    <attribute name='new_gradecode' />        
                                    <attribute name='modifiedon' />
                                    <attribute name='new_studentinformationid' />
                                    <filter type='and'>
                                        <condition attribute='modifiedon' value='{0}' operator='on-or-after'/>
                                    </filter>
                                    <order attribute='modifiedon' descending='true' />
                                    <link-entity name='annotation' from='objectid' to='new_studentinformationid'                                                                        alias='Notes' link-type='outer'>        
                                        <attribute name='documentbody'/>       

                                 <filter type='and'>
                                        <condition attribute='createdon' value='{0}' operator='on-or-after'/>
                                    </filter>
                                    <order attribute='createdon' descending='true' />                               
                             </link-entity> 
                        </entity>
                            </fetch>"
```

Every record has more than one image attached to it in Notes entity, however I want to transfer the latest picture ONLY. I have tried using the `createdon` in the order attribute but it keep bringing the images with the record till the oldest one. I only want it to bring the latest image and stop it there and move to the next record.

How can I limit it to querying only the latest image attached with the record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `<link-entity>` doesn't allow it.

If you want a quick cheat around this limitation, you could do this (we do it all the time when specs go nuts):

1. Add a lookup to `annotation` to your `new_studentinformation` entity (keep it out of forms)
2. Register a plugin on `new_studentinformation` (Pre-Op, Sync, both for Retrieve and RetrieveMultiple) in which you fill the new attribute with the reference to the record you want in the report. I expect this to take 15 minutes tops.
3. Now switch the `from` attribute in the `link-entity` to the new one

BONUS: If your plugin is designed correctly, the reference in the custom attribute (and consequently your report) will automagically update itself.

Comment: so to keep it simple you are saying, whenever a new image is added to the annotation, the field will update with the latest value and the query would become something like:
<link-entity name='annotation' from='<new lookup field>' to='new_studentinformationid'                                                                        alias='Notes' link-type='outer'>        
                                        <attribute name='documentbody'/>

Comment: Thank you Alex, I didn't use a plugin but your answer put me in the right path and I solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution for your problem which will save you time and effort which you will put in making a plugin.

You should make a javascript resource , add a hidden field on your form. 
Run that javascript on OnSave event. Store that document body in a text view. 
Just query the document body text area while you are retrieving the image.
It may sound a hack! but it will increase the efficiency of your code.

Comment: how do you propose i save the image's document body in the text field? if i use the javascript to save the document body in the text area. it will load only once when the page loads, what if i add another image? I would have to refresh the page manually? I am not inclined towards that.